# add custom popover form in Gutenberg editor wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ecmascript-5, wordpress-gutenberg

I am a newbie in WordPress plugin development. How to add custom popover form in Gutenberg editor WordPress?

```
            var Button = function ( props ) {
                return wp.element.createElement( wp.blockEditor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                    icon: 'editor-code',
                    title: 'XXXXX',
                    onClick: function () {
                                ///// write code here after click open pop a form
                        return wp.element.createElement('div', );
                    }
                });
            }
            
            wp.richText.registerFormatType( 'my-custom-format/form-popup', {
                title: 'Pop Form',
                tagName: 'popform',
                className: null,
                attributes: {
                    text
                },
                edit: Button,
            } );
        } )( window.wp );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg provides multiple components for "popovers". The two most common are the [`Modal`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/components/src/modal) component and the [`Popover`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/components/src/popover) component. There are usage examples on those pages.

Comment: I have used the Modal component. I won't able to embed text on Gutenberg editor from the modal's text field. Can you help with this?

Comment: @RohitUrane I'm not sure what you mean by "embed text on Gutenberg editor from the modal's text field". But you should be able to store the value of text fields in either a block `attribute` or `post meta`, then output that wherever you want/need. Are you building a custom block?

Comment: No. Modal opens on the editor by clicking the toolbar option. In Modal, I am searching link which put inside the post by click on the title. Screenshot link: https://snipboard.io/pzwAf4.jpg